# How do I restore a property sheet to its default value?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-4.0, propertysheet

Let's say I carry out the following steps immediately after first installing and opening Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

1. `File` -> `New` -> `Project` -> `Win32 Console App` -> `Finish`.
2. Go to the `Property Manager` pane -> Expand `Debug | Win32` -> Right click `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` -> Select `Properties`.
3. Wildly change settings in a clueless manner, and generally act like a fool.
4. Click `Apply`, save the project, and close Visual Studio.

How do I restore the `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user` property sheet to its default, "factory" settings?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the official way, but it does work...

The default property sheets are stored in the following directory:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0
```

And if you delete them, they will be automatically recreated by Visual Studio using the default settings next time that it is launched.

So you can simply delete `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` from that directory and restart VS.

Putting it all together, from the command line, simply issue the following command:

```
del %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props
```

Comment: The default `Microsoft.Cpp.[Platform].user.props` files contain no settings, so this does this job just fine.